# Animating Launch of Home Screen?

Tags: android, animation, launcher

I have the following code:

```
    PackageManager mPackageManager = getPackageManager();
    ComponentName component = new ComponentName("com.myPackage", "com.myPackage.GhostLauncher");
    mPackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(component, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);

    mPackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(component, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_out_left, R.anim.slide_in_left);
```

Basically every time this code is launched, the dialog box that prompts the user to select a default home screen comes up, which is what was desired. Once the user selects that default Home Screen, it is launched. My question isn't too difficult, I'm just not sure how to go about doing this: when I tap the button that corresponds to the above code, the dialog box prompting the user to select a default home screen slides in from the right. However, the once the user makes a selection, the Home Screen itself appears using the default animation. How can I override that second animation to also be a slide from right?

Comment: I doubt that is possible, as you are not the one calling `startActivity()` for the actual home screen -- the chooser is. Ideally, the chooser would copy the settings, but that's up to the implementation of the chooser.

Answer (score 0):

You can try moving

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_out_left, R.anim.slide_in_left);
```

to `GhostLauncher.onCreate()`, perhaps it's not too late to override the animations because the Activity has not been created yet.